# What design patterns are available for Data Classes in Java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a complex class in Java whose responsibility it to mainly store Data. I was wondering if there are any design patterns available to guide such use cases.
To be more specific, the class is something which records the overall performance of a student per semester.

```
Class StudentReport{
    cgpa = 3.1;
    Set <SubjectReport> perSubjectReportSet;
    overallFeedback = "..."
    ...
}

Class SubjectReport{
   subjectName = "Subject_A";
   gpa = 2.4;

   // Test Details
   test = Pass;
   testQuestionAnsweredCount = 8;
   testQuestionsCount = 10;
   testFeedback = None; // Feedback if FAIL

   // Assignment Details
   assignment = Pass;
   ...

   //Exam Details
   finalExam = Fail;
   examQuestionAnsweredCount = 5;
   examCorrectlyAnsweredQuestionCount = 2;
   examQuestionsCount = 10;
   examFeedback = "Blah Blah OOP" // Feedback if FAIL
}
```

Comment: I don't understand You. Have You seen ever some Java book?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the question. This SO community does not seem to  welcome/encourage this. It is very sad.

Answer (score 0):

A design pattern to encapsulate class attributes, is **the private class data** pattern. It seeks to reduce the visibility of the class attributes

Answer (score 0):

The description: "*I have a complex class in Java whose responsibility it to mainly store Data*" is a bit to general, does not every object store data combined with behavior?

You're example code does show a design: [the composition pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: `StudentReport` having a set of `SubjectReport` objects does not make a _Composite_, if that's what you're referring to.